# What are the advantages of PS3 Move?

Tags: playstation-move, heavy-rain

If someone has tried this out, I would like to know the response times etc. I really loved Heavy Rain and wanted to buy this for my second play through.

Comment: Sorry but this question is just a discussion. Yes, I find it worth buying, but others will dislike the game or already have a Wii or will be buying Kinect first and claim no. So either you want to know the technical specs of Move or you have to come up with something else.

Comment: so should I delete the question or is there something else that I can do?

Comment: You could ask what benefits the Move brings to Heavy Rain specifically, or you could ask for a list of its advantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the generic gestures to mimic real life movement lacking when scaled up for the Move.

I played Heavy Rain when it came out on a DualShock and enjoyed it. When I started a new game using the Move and I found the Move controller input to be lacking. I only played until your wife and kids come home but I didn't enjoy the required arm sweeping and wrist flicking. What was a flick of your thumb becomes a whole arm movement. There is probably a lot of room for your personal tastes to affect your opinion of this experience.